# Use Multi-layer Keras Model as Convolution Filter

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a two layer bidirectional recurrent stack in the final layer of an existing model that is trained to extract text from images of constant size. I am adding an additional convolution layer to the existing architecture before the recurrent stack to enable text detection over larger images. The model looks like this:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
the_input (InputLayer)       (None, 64, 128, 3)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 128, 48)       3648
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 64, 48)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 64, 64)        76864
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 64, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 64, 128)       204928
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 32, 128)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 1, 2048)        67110912
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 1, 1, 1)           0
=================================================================
```

conv2d_4 is the new convolution layer to enable images of sizes other than 128 x 64. lambda_1 is a presence indicator variable with one value per sliding window position. The code to create the following models is as follows:

```
input_data = Input(name='the_input', shape=input_shape)

def add_conv(prev_component, kernel_dims, num_filters, max_pool_dims=None, padding='same'):
    cnv = Conv2D(num_filters, kernel_dims, activation='relu',
                 padding=padding)(prev_component)
    if max_pool_dims is not None:
        cnv = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=max_pool_dims)(cnv)
    return cnv

prev = input_data
prev = add_conv(prev, (5, 5), 48, max_pool_dims=(2, 2))
prev = add_conv(prev, (5, 5), 64, max_pool_dims=(2, 1))
prev = add_conv(prev, (5, 5), 128, max_pool_dims=(2, 2))
#[kernel_height, kernel_width, prev_filter_count, new_filter_count]
prev = add_conv(prev, (8, 32), time_dense_size, padding='valid')

def is_plate_func(windowed_data):
    is_plate_w = K.variable(K.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1, shape=(1, 1, 2048, 1)))
    is_plate_b = K.variable(K.constant(.1, shape=[1]))
    is_plate_out = K.bias_add(K.conv2d(windowed_data, is_plate_w), is_plate_b)
    return is_plate_out

is_plate_lambda = Lambda(is_plate_func)(prev)
Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=[is_plate_lambda]).summary()
```

The code for the recurrent stack that I would like to attach to the model in the same fashion as lambda_1 was attached is as follows:

```
bdrnn_model = Sequential()
bdrnn_model.add(Reshape((2048, 1), input_shape=(1, 1, 2048)))
for idx in range(num_backward_layers):
    if idx == num_backward_layers - 1:
        merge_mode = 'concat'
    else:
        merge_mode = 'sum'
    bdrnn_model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(rnn_size, return_sequences=True),
                                  merge_mode=merge_mode))
bdrnn_model.add(Dense(num_output_characters + 2, activation='relu'))
```

Is there a way to get Keras to use 'bdrnn_model' as a convolution filter?

Comment: What do you mean use a model as a convolution filter? You just want apply a model in a sliding window fashion?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I would like to use a single set of trained parameters in the recurrent stack as a filter applied at every sliding window position for a window of size (128 x 64). The tensorflow backend's conv2d function enables specifying a trainable filter as a tensor. I am having difficulty representing the stacked RNN as a tensor. Is there an easier way to do this than via the conv2d function in the tensorflow backend?

Comment: No, you can't use a model as a convolution filter, what you want is a sliding window, which can't be done with TF's conv2D function. You can't convert a model into a tensor. You can always do the sliding window manually.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I will train the model with images of size equal to the window size and will evaluate it with slices of larger images.